# I have to determine if model has more than 4 objects or less

Tags: python, django

If Model has more than 4 than everything works fine. but if there is less than 4 `.count()` returns 0

```
posts_num = Post.objects.filter(author__id= self.kwargs["pk"]).count()
            print(posts_num)
            if posts_num >= 4:
                page_author_post = Post.objects.filter(author__id= self.kwargs["pk"]).order_by('-post_date')[:4]
            else:
                page_author_post = Post.objects.filter(author__id= self.kwargs["pk"]).order_by('-post_date')[:posts_num]
            current_user = self.request.user.id
    
    context["page_author_post"] = page_author_post
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you want to retrieve the first four posts or all existing posts if there are less than four? You could achieve this by simply using `Post.objects.filter(author__id= self.kwargs["pk"]).order_by('-post_date')[:4]`. If less than four posts exist, only those will be returned. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: Would you post the exact error and some more information.

Comment: @SivaSankar there is no error but of there is less than 4 objects they are not displaying on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the slicing using `[:posts_num]` in else condition. It is already is in the else condition, which means posts_num will always be less than 4 (i.e, 1 or 2 or 3).

Your code would be like:

```
posts_num = Post.objects.filter(author__id= self.kwargs["pk"]).count()
            print(posts_num)
            if posts_num >= 4:
                page_author_post = Post.objects.filter(author__id= self.kwargs["pk"]).order_by('-post_date')[:4]
            else:
                page_author_post = Post.objects.filter(author__id= self.kwargs["pk"]).order_by('-post_date') # observe the change here
            current_user = self.request.user.id
    
    context["page_author_post"] = page_author_post
```

Comment: `print(post_num)` still returns 0 so its not working

Comment: I think it is not the exact error. May be database doesn't have enough objects. Would you post the exact error and double check how many objects using pub